# How to disable Nvidia MX230?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, battery, nvidia-geforce

I am using Ubuntu in Vivobook and am experiencing terrible battery life. It could be due to the MX230 included. Is there a way to shift to iGPU?

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without knowing: what you're doing on the computer, is the machine too hot/cold? Is the battery nearing the end of its life? What does "terrible" mean? 20 minutes? 4 hours? With a more complete question, you may receive a more complete answer 

Comment: I apologise for incorrectly framing the question. I just meant to ask how to disable the MX230

Answer (score 0):

So long as you have the nvidia driver installed, you can manually switch between the video devices using the nvidia X Server Settings utility:

[image: nvidia X Server Settings]

Open the application and choose "PRIME Profiles" from the list on the left. You will then see some options on the right:

[image: PRIME Profiles]

The options are broken down as such:

| Label | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| NVIDIA (Performance Mode) | Prioritise graphics and to heck with power saving |
| NVIDIA On-Demand | Automatically switch between NVIDIA dedicated graphics and the on-board Intel graphics device depending on the task |
| Intel (Power Saving Mode) | Only use the on-board Intel graphics device |

Some notebooks only show two options, so do not worry if you do not have the exact same list.

***Note:** If you are unable to find nvidia X Server Settings in your application menu, then you might not be using an nvidia driver. You can confirm this by opening Terminal and using* `sudo lshw -C video`. *You will see something like this:*

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b1080000-b10fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:38 memory:b1400000-b17fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Under `configuration` there is a `driver` value. If it says `nouveau`, then you're using the open driver. If it says `nvidia` you're using the proprietary driver.

Hope this answers your question and helps resolve the battery life issues you're experiencing.